# Pyramid and Cornice XML renderer

Tags: python, rest, python-3.x, pyramid, cornice

Using [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) and [Cornice](https://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), how can I tell Cornice to return XML responses instead of JSON? It seems that by default JSON is used, and [this article](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2013/multi-format-restful-api-with-cornice) shows how to add a new `text/plain` renderer to Cornice. Error responses still contain a JSON body.

How do I switch to XML?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are two ways to return XML data:

Render XML with Mako:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<information>
</information>
```

Set the Response Content Type:

```
request.response.content_type = "text/xml"  
return {'data': 'something'}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to follow [this](http://akbarahmed.com/2012/01/16/output-xml-using-pyramid-and-mako/) approach? I haven't tried it yet, but does [Mako](http://pyramid-mako.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) work for Cornice?